# Archiving. What are the best practices?

Tags: interaction-design, user-expectation, interface, filter, dashboard

We are having a debate about a new feature we want to implement. Our system has a long list of items with five statuses (Public, staged, scheduled, draft, disabled). One of the users' main problems is the old items they don't use anymore that clutter the list view. They don't want to delete these items as they would lose data. They want to keep them out of sight.

[image]

We proposed to add archive as one of the statuses, therefore not adding an extra UI to an already cluttered filtering bar (there are 10+ filters at this point)

There is strong opposition from PMs as they think this is not solving the customer's real problem, as they have to unselect this status to hide the archived items.They want to create a separate functionality for archiving and putting it away from statuses.

Our customers are divided between 2 solutions; there isn't any clear winner between 2 options.

Do you have any suggestions or insight on this issue?

Comment: Do you happen to know if archived records are stored and retrieved differently than ones that are "live"? It might take more than a filter or different view if that's the case.

Comment: We don't have archived reports implemented yet, but I assume that they would rarely interact with these reports and use this functionality as a fail-safe.

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of adding archived documents as a status, you can add them as another type of document. So in this navigation you could have the following:

```
Statuses (3)     Archives     Whatever
```

Optionally, you could do it the way Invision does it:

[image]

In both cases, it's the same: you have two taxonomies. In the first one, you can browse between a "live" type of document. In the second, you can browse between "archived" documents. Also, the variables for each document could be the same in many cases (probably not in your case, but generally speaking)

Comment: Yes, the more I think about this issue more I am aligned with this solution.